# Presentation Mode/ Presentation Settings in RDP Windows Server 2022

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server, presentation, windows-server-2022

I cannot open presentation mode or settings in my remote connection, with Windows Server 2022.
I have the .exe file, but when I open it , nothing happens. No windows, no nothing
Am I missing something?

I tried activating it on a desktop computer:
https://web.archive.org/web/20121014132655/http://www.dubuque.k12.ia.us/it/mobilitycenter/

But without any success

Can someone share some insights in this?
I need it to try to keep the computer not going into idle (besides the things I have tried here: [Prevent RDP from going idle (not idle-locking or idle-logout, just show as active)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76562945/prevent-rdp-from-going-idle-not-idle-locking-or-idle-logout-just-show-as-activ))

Thank you